# Rails 4: column reference "updated_at" is ambiguous with Postgres

Tags: ruby, postgresql, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to query the database with a DateTime range for the '`updated_at`' field. The front end sends queries in a JSON array:

```
["2015-09-01 00:00:00","2015-10-02 23:00:00"]
```

**At the Rails controller, I parse the two strings to DateTime using:**

```
start_date = DateTime.parse(params[:date_range_arr][0])
end_date = DateTime.parse(params[:date_range_arr][1])

#...
@events = @events.where('updated_at BETWEEN ? AND ?,
       start_date, end_date
)
```

**The queries show:**

```
WHERE (updated_at BETWEEN '2015-09-01 00:00:00.000000' AND '2015-10-02 23:00:00.000000')
```

**And the errors are:**

```
ActionView::Template::Error (PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column reference "updated_at" is ambiguous
LINE 1: ...texts"."id" = "events"."context_id" WHERE (updated_at...
```

Comment: I'm going to guess whatever is in `#...` is actually pretty important in this case.  You're probably joining tables or something?  There's likely more than 1 `updated_at` column in play, so it's ambiguous.

Comment: Thank you! It is because of the join table in the search, just like you said.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do you have by any chance a default scope with a join or an include on the Event model or in the code above what's included in the original question?

Either way, you simply need to be more specific with your query as follow:

```
#...
@events = @events.where('events.updated_at BETWEEN ? AND ?,
   start_date, end_date
)
```

Comment: yes, I do have join table in the search. I just tried your suggestion to make the query more specific! It works! You rock! I will accept your answer in a few minutes as allowed. THANKS!

Comment: No problem, glad to help! :)

Comment: I wish there was a way to have it choose the primary table as what is being referenced (90% of the time - here 'events'), unless we specify otherwise - maybe throw a line into console output in dev about it to aid in troubleshooting - but not 'crash' for crying out loud.  Yet another case where we have to drop down to SQL-type queries in our where statements, created by this 'feature'.  It is as if the source-coders forgot the goal is web-scripting functionality - not C++ style absolute specificity.